# FFMPEG fails to find any files matching the regexp

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, video-codecs

I want to convert sequence of 40 images to a video. The problem is that ffmpeg could not find any of the inputs images matching the regexp in the command. What am I doing wrong please?

I ran the following commands:

```
> ffmpeg -f image2 -i "img%0d.jpg" -vcodec mpeg4 -y -v "verbose" 07_seq_wire.avi 
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release.    Please use avconv instead.
img%0d.jpg: No such file or directory


> ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  69812 Apr 11 01:54 img01.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  70858 Apr 11 01:54 img02.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  71481 Apr 11 01:54 img03.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  71528 Apr 11 01:54 img04.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  71470 Apr 11 01:54 img05.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  71534 Apr 11 01:54 img06.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  70908 Apr 11 01:54 img07.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  70633 Apr 11 01:54 img08.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  70059 Apr 11 01:54 img09.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  70021 Apr 11 01:54 img10.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  69726 Apr 11 01:54 img11.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  70896 Apr 11 01:54 img12.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  72123 Apr 11 01:54 img13.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  72605 Apr 11 01:54 img14.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  73501 Apr 11 01:54 img15.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  73743 Apr 11 01:54 img16.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  74401 Apr 11 01:54 img17.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  74697 Apr 11 01:54 img18.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  75371 Apr 11 01:54 img19.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  74802 Apr 11 01:54 img20.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  74802 Apr 11 01:55 img21.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  75371 Apr 11 01:55 img22.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  74697 Apr 11 01:55 img23.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  74401 Apr 11 01:55 img24.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  73743 Apr 11 01:55 img25.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  73501 Apr 11 01:55 img26.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  72605 Apr 11 01:55 img27.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  72123 Apr 11 01:55 img28.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  70896 Apr 11 01:55 img29.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  69726 Apr 11 01:55 img30.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  70021 Apr 11 01:55 img31.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  70059 Apr 11 01:55 img32.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  70633 Apr 11 01:55 img33.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  70908 Apr 11 01:55 img34.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  71534 Apr 11 01:55 img35.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  71470 Apr 11 01:55 img36.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  71528 Apr 11 01:55 img37.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  71481 Apr 11 01:55 img38.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  70858 Apr 11 01:56 img39.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  69812 Apr 11 01:56 img40.jpg
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `img%0d.jpg` to `img%2d.jpg`.

It worked for me when I did this.

You will have to set a bit rate with `-b:v 1024K`, or a quality level with `-q:v 2` (range from 1 to 31, 2–5 being sane choices) to change the quality of the output. Without specifying anything, the default bit rate will be very low and result in bad visual quality.

Comment: The problem with the "funny" looking output is the default bitrate which is too low. Changing the format doesn't really help solve the actual issue—specifying a bitrate would be preferred.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The %2d thing worked. However the video is still quite low quality. Even when I change the bitrate to 1024K. In the terminal output I can always see the same value of 2621.7 kbits/s everytime I change the bitrate:

Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=   40 fps=  0 q=31.0 Lsize=     512kB time=1.60 bitrate=2621.7kbits/s    
video:505kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.300001%

Comment: @dawe134 Please update your question with the full, uncut command output and ping me when you did so. I'll check then.